# Variable not initializing by throwing "command not found"

Tags: bash, scripts

I've my bash file and got error while running it. I'm just storing parameter in a variable as:

```
cmd = $1
```

But an error is showing every time when I ran my script as **`bash path/to/myfile.sh`**, and it throws:

```
path/to/myfile.sh: line 3: cmd: command not found
```

However above isn't a syntax one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, any one who's going to see this solution, if you know the reason behind it just let me know.
I will be glad.

We just need to remove the spaces around assignment operator.

```
cmd=$1
```

Comment: BASH assumes that spaces have meaning -- they are a *delimiter*. Spaces separate commands and options from each other.